# Accidentally updating child variables

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, dom-events

I'm currently working in a page with parent/child components. Somehow my child component gets updated when I manage its variables in the parent component.
**What I'm trying to do:**

1. My child component has a 'site' variable with all the data i need to send via API
2. My parent component has a Save button to send the child data to the Back-end
3. When 'site' changes in the child component, I'm emitting an event `@change` to the parent component
4. The `@change` event contains all the data I need, but not in the format I want
5. There is a function `submit()` that gets this data and modify the one of the arrays so that this: ['foo','bar'] becomes this 'foo,bar'
6. **The problem** when I do the step '5' my child component gets updated

The child component inside the parent component

```js
<configuracoes :configuracoes="configuracoes" @change="setData"
      v-if="currentPage === 'configs'"/>
```

The change event emitted by the child component

```js
this.$emit("change", this.site);
```

The important part of 'site' var

```js
site: {
  seo: {
   keywords: [],
             ...
           },
          ...
    },
```

The `setData()` function

```js
setData(data) {
    this.data = data;
},
```

The `submitData()` function

```js
submitData() {
    if (this.currentPage === "configs") {

        let data = ({}, Object.assign(this.data))
        let keywords = data.seo.keywords.join(',')
        data.seo.keywords = keywords
        this.$store.dispatch("sites/updateSite", {
            empresa_id: this.user.empresa_id,
            site_id: this.siteId,
            dados: data,
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm declaring another variable let data to avoid updating this.site variable, but no success

Comment: `data.seo.keywords = keywords` is probably the cause of the child's data changing

Comment: By the way, why do you need this comma-expression? `let data = ({}, Object.assign(this.data))`

Comment: @hlfrmn I was trying to modify the data variable without changing the site var, but i was doing it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is an issue with how you're "copying" your `this.data` object.

```js
let data = ({}, Object.assign(this.data)); // this doesn't work
console.log(data === this.data); // true

const dataCopy = Object.assign({}, this.data); // this works
console.log(dataCopy === this.data); // false
```

The way `Object.assign` works, all the properties will be copied over into the first argument. Since you only pass a single argument, it doesn't change and is still pointing to the same old object.

---

If you use the correct way, you will most likely still run into the same issue. The reason is that `data.seo` is not a primitive value (a number or a string), but is an object.

This means that the whole `seo` object will be copied over into the new copy. In other words, even though `dataCopy !== this.data`, `dataCopy.seo === this.data.seo`. This is known as "shallow copy".

You want to make sure you DO NOT modify the original `seo` object, here are a few ways to do that.

```js
let goodCopy;
const newKeywords = this.data.seo.keywords.join(',');

// use object spread syntax
goodCopy = {
    ...this.data,
    seo: {
        ...this.data.seo,
        keywords: newKeywords,
    },
};

// use Object.assign
goodCopy = Object.assign(
    {},
    this.data,
    {
        seo: Object.assign(
            {},
            this.data.seo,
            {keywords: newKeywords}),
    });

// create a copy of "seo", and then change it to your liking
const seoCopy = {...this.data.seo};
seoCopy.keywords = newKeywords;
goodCopy = Object.assign({}, this.data, {seo: seoCopy});

this.$store.dispatch('sites/updateSite', {
    empresa_id: this.user.empresa_id,
    site_id: this.siteId,
    dados: goodCopy,
});
```

If you want to read up on ways to copy a JavaScript object, [here's a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yesterday i was looking for a fix and found how Objects and references work. Despite beeing a programmer for so long, there is still a lot to learn 
(i cant vote because i dont have enough reputation)